# How to place items in Bootstrap modal's backdrop?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm using regular Bootstrap 3 modals, but want to tweak them a little bit.

I want to place a logo on the upper left and the close button on the upper right of the backdrop, like this:

[image]

I've been playing around with some CSS pseudo selectors to insert content, but nothing of that worked.
Maybe one of you guys has an idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your code please? But maybe `float: left` and `float: right` will do the work for you.

Comment: Can't you insert those elements on the HTML ?  why pseudo-selectors....http://www.bootply.com/AQafF1LaVw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert those elements on the normal HTML for modals and use the classnames `pull-right` and `pull-left`:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
   <img class="pull-left" src="YourLogo.png">
   <div class="pull-right">Close-Ico</div>
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        ....
```

Check this example **http://www.bootply.com/AQafF1LaVw**

Comment: Thanks, this worked out great and easy for me. I wasn't aware that I can place content outside of the modal-dialog div.

Answer (score 0):

You could put a new hidden element in the body and only show it when the backdrop is shown. The `.modal-open` is only applied to the body tag when the modal is open.

```
.modal-open-inner {
    display:none;
}

.modal-open .modal-open-inner {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

http://codeply.com/go/HdMsy0WdWS